# How to get a query retrieving two objects from Parse via Swift

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, merge

I have a parse database as in the picture.

[image]

I need to retrieve with a query code, two objects, for example the last created dates of type 2 and 3.

I am trying the codes below, but dont know how to merge these two queries (query2 and query3)? Or might there be another way to retrieve these two objects as one table?

```
    var query2 = PFQuery(className: "stories")
    query2.whereKey("Type", equalTo: 2)
    query2.addDescendingOrder("createdAt")
    query2.getFirstObject()

    var query3 = PFQuery(className: "stories")
    query3.whereKey("Type", equalTo: 3)
    query3.addDescendingOrder("createdAt")
    query3.getFirstObject()
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you could do exactly what you currently have with 1 query. You could combine them but only to get back an array of all 2 and 3 types and then split them out yourself.

If the issue is making 2 different network requests then you could create a cloud code function to run the 2 queries and return the results in a single response.

Comment: Hello Wain, thanks for the answer. So isnt there a way to combine the results of query2 and query3?

Comment: Not exactly, as I (and the other answer) say you can only get all 2 & 3 types and then filter locally to get the first of each...

Answer (score 0):

you can do this one query as well

```
var query2 = PFQuery(className: "stories")
query2.whereKey("Type", equalTo: 2)
query2.whereKey("Type", equalTo: 3)
query2.addDescendingOrder("createdAt")
```

You can change you approach too , you can send array to compare and sort results

```
query2.whereKey("Type", containedIn: @[2,3])
query2.addDescendingOrder("createdAt")
```

After this don't use getFirstObject ; get all array and get your desired results using predicate or any else , this will save one network call as well.

This is for getting 2 values from Array

```
NSArray *fullArray= All objects from the parse ;

NSMutableArray *selectedObjectsArray = [NSMutableArray array];

for(int i=0 ; i<fullArray.count ; i++){
    if (selectedObjectsArray.count==1 && ![[[selectedObjectsArray objectAtIndex:0] objcetForKey:@"type"] isEqualToString:[[Full array objectAtIndex:i] objcetForKey:@"type"]]) {
        [selectedObjectsArray addObject:[fullArray objectAtIndex]];
        break ;
    }else{
        [selectedObjectsArray addObject:[fullArray objectAtIndex]];
    }
}
```

In Swift (i m not too good in swift so double check swift code before using)

```
for object in fullArray {
    if (selectedObjectsArray.count==1 && ![[selectedObjectsArray[0][@"type"] isEqualToString:fullArray[i][@"type"]) {
        selectedObjectsArray[1]=[fullArray[i];
        break ;
    }else{
        selectedObjectsArray[0]=[fullArray[i];
    }

}
```

Comment: Hello Mohammad, thank you for the answer, after these codes, it will give all inputs of type 2 and 3, how can I get only the last created objects of type 2 and 3? Finally I need 2 objects at the end. Thats the reason why I was trying to make two different queries with get first object and then tried to merge them.

Comment: I edited answer but i m not too good in swift so double check swift code before using

Comment: Thank you very much Mohammad, I will try this method.